# Differential cross section for photon scattering on fixed magnetic dipole

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering, scattering-cross-section

Photon with energy $\hbar\omega$ scattering on a fixed particle with magnetic momentum $\vec{\mu} = \mu \vec s$. 
How to calculate a differential and total cross section for the photon.

I've found in Messiah's book that
$$\frac {d\sigma_{i\rightarrow f}} {d\Omega} = \frac{L^6\omega^2}{4\pi^2}\left|T_{i\rightarrow f}\right|^2,$$
$$T_{i\rightarrow f} = \left<\alpha \vec{k}_i\left|T\right|\alpha \vec{k}_f\right>,$$
$$T = H'+H'\frac{1}{E-H+i\varepsilon}H'$$

But I don't realize how to calculate the Hamiltonian and the matrix element $T_{i\rightarrow f}$ for this system.